# Reading URLs from NSOpenPanel causes crash with SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

This code crashes with SIGABRT:

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel  = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel runModalForTypes:nil];
NSArray* URLs = [openPanel URLs];
for (NSString* item in URLs)
{
    NSLog(item); // here it crashes with SIGABRT
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with the code but I'm a beginner at Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `for (NSURL *url in URLs)` instead. For some reason, you are incorrectly using an `NSString`.

Also, you should be logging like this: `NSLog(@"%@", url);` This is the way you should do it. You shouldn't be passing the object directly to `NSLog`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. I would probably use `NSLog(@"%@", [url path]);`.

Comment: @enchilada Thanks for the answer, my code works great now! But coming from C++ I would have expected a compile error in this case, is there no pointer-type checks in objective-c?

Comment: Sure, there are pointer-type checks. You didn't originally get a compile-time warning because NSLog does indeed expect a string, and you had written "NSString *item" previously so you didn't get any warning. You should have gotten a warning with "NSURL *url" though. But I think in both cases you should have gotten some kind of a warning when you pass an object directly into NSLog. I seem to recall having seen such a warning. Maybe it depends on the compiler settings.